# Selecting form with ID not working but selecting it with $('form') works

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, forms

I found something strange in my code, I solved it by selecting element with $('form') however there could be one or more forms on my page to avoid globally selecting, I just want to select a specific form element.

My problem is starts with serialize(), selecting my specific form by using ID selector works but I cant serialize while .submit event. But if I select form with ID ($("#formid")) serialize() not works on form submit.

my JS code is :

```
var entrylist = $('form');  //<< if I put $("#entrylist) here, 'data' displays null.
  entrylist.submit(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  var data = JSON.stringify($(this).serializeObject())
  console.log(data);
});
```

and form is :

```
<form id="entrylist" action="" method="post">
 <textarea name="inputarea"></textarea>
 some more inputs.. bla bla
</form>
```

The result with $('form')

```
{"inputarea":"brobrobrobro","thread_id":"399196","csrf_token":"aIw3dXzCbJGp4c32PzPeo9pVDKwTkCuQotyRWVll"}
```

The result with $('#entrylist')

```
{}
```

Note: serializeObject is a custom function that I get it from https://stackoverflow.com/a/1186309/1932414

Comment: You're not using the same ID twice, are you?

Comment: Try `console.log($('form'))` and `console.log($('#entrylist'))` to compare

Comment: Can you create a jsFiddle that demonstrates this?

Comment: wow! I was so sure there are not duplicate of #entrylist, yet somehow there was.. Thanks for pointing this guys! my page had a include file, and this makes two entrylist!

Comment: [serializeObject](https://github.com/danheberden/serializeObject) has been updated to [serializeForm](https://github.com/danheberden/jquery-serializeForm).

Comment: @Blazemonger I realized there is another #entrylist in my code, that cause my problem, thanks again! :)